# How to insert file into Oracle with jdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, blob

I was trying to do giving byte array as SqlLobValue() but it doesn't work.

```
public void sendEmailWithAccountInfoPDF(String toEmail, byte[] pdf) {
        String SQL_ADD_EMAIL = "insert into emails_for_sending " +
        "(to_email, attach_type, attach_name, attach_body) " +
        "values (:to_email, :attach_type, :attach_name, :attach_body);";

   Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
   params.put("to_email", toEmail);

   params.put("attach_type", "application/pdf");
   params.put("attach_name", "info.pdf");
   params.put("attach_body", new SqlLobValue(pdf));

   jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_ADD_EMAIL, params);
}
```

But it gives me "SqlLobValue only supports SQL types Blob and Clob".

How to insert file into Oracle with jdbcTemplate properly?

Comment: Post the full stack trace.  Is the exception thrown by a Spring class?  If yes, find the source code to see why the exception is thrown.  If no, is the attach_body column actually a blob/clob type?

Answer (score 0):

The LobCreator/LobHandler provides the following support for LOB in- and output:

BLOB

byte[] – getBlobAsBytes and setBlobAsBytes

InputStream – getBlobAsBinaryStream and setBlobAsBinaryStream

CLOB

String – getClobAsString and setClobAsString

InputStream – getClobAsAsciiStream and setClobAsAsciiStream

Reader – getClobAsCharacterStream and setClobAsCharacterStream